# Is Javascript any better than before as mentioned in the O'Reilly Javascript Patterns book for closures and anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript

This is a quote from the O'Reilly Javascript Patterns book:

> JavaScript is also an unusual language. It doesn’t have classes, and
>   functions are first class objects used for many tasks. Initially the
>   language was considered deficient by many developers, but in more
>   recent years these sentiments have changed. Interestingly, languages
>   such as Java and PHP started adding features such as closures and
>   anonymous functions, which JavaScript developers have been enjoying
>   and taking for granted for a while.

and that's it.  I really don't understand how Javascript was considered "deficient" before, and now is not, because other languages like Java or PHP has added closures and anonymous functions?   Aren't they just generic computing concepts?  Aren't they available in other languages like Ruby?   So I don't really know how Javascript is now not "deficient" because Java and PHP added closures and anonymous functions as their features?  Why is that?

Comment: It was considered "deficient" because it was different from the dominant programming languages and Javascript's lack of certain "features" those programmers were used to that Javascript didn't have. Over the last ten years, many things have changed, and Javascript has matured with the web. In the meantime, many very good "programmers" began taking web scripting seriously or adopted Javascript as a serious language to work in. The browser grew up, the web became profitable, and progress happened. I still know some C programmers who scoff at it (and PHP, and Ruby). Who cares?

Comment: Also, "considered deficient" != "actually deficient". Many C constructs are completely unnecessary in a browser environment, but Javascript is "deficient" in these. It doesn't really matter to a browser, but to a C/C++/Java programmer, it might feel like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what it's referring to is that in the past many developers considered JavaScript as a 'toy' language and only used it to do quick Web UI tasks like validation etc. without bothering to understand how the language really worked.

In recent years the 'hidden' features of JavaScript such as closures, prototypal inheritance etc. have come to the fore and people are now taking JavaScript much more seriously as a 'real' language.

So JavaScript was never really "deficient" but people may have thought that it was due to their misconceptions about the language.

Comment: I guess it can make sense if we say Javascript does have some advanced features... but still, the "deficiency" is not helped by having advanced features, just that we can't just add closures and anonymous functions to any bad languages and call it "now it is good"

Answer (score 2):

I personally think it's a poor editing job.

The paragraph should have read (bold addition is mine and is just a suggestion on how
to read it):

> JavaScript is also an unusual language. It doesn’t have classes, and
>   functions are first class objects used for many tasks. Initially the
>   language was considered deficient by many developers, but in more
>   recent years these sentiments have changed **due to a better and more uniform browser support, extensive work done by various ECMA editions and evolution of various JavaScript frameworks. All, or much, of that change is a direct result of ever-expanding movement of software products to the Web and growing demand for a lightweight language for mobile applications (*this one can be somewhat argued)*.**
>
> Interestingly, languages such as Java and PHP started adding features
>   such as closures and anonymous functions, which JavaScript developers
>   have been enjoying and taking for granted for a while.

Answer (score 0):

For years, JavaScript has been known to only be a browser language, for (simple) features that required more dynamic and/or flexibility than offered by HTML and CSS.

For several years now, JavaScript evolved as a language and as platform, offering powerful libraries, which also removed certain cross-browser incompatibilities. With rise of these libraries, community actually only started to learn how to use some powerful concepts of JavaScript, such as closures and prototypal inheritance.

They have not been widely used nor known even to JavaScript developers before, since JavaScript is in its basics very simple language, and most developers didn't even have to learn it as you'd learn Python, C or Java - all they had to look at were tutorials and many of them didn't include these language features.

Duo to the increase in popularity, JavaScript (officially ECMAScript) has received several 'editions', where features have been added to the language itself. [Latest edition](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php) (still under development) will introduce some radical  novelties (considered are classes, module system, iterators, algebraic types among others), so JS will become even better, more structured and more easily maintainable language.

JavaScript is raising in popularity on server side also (node.js), and proves to be easy, fast and enough powerful language to do (almost) any kind of work. Node widely 'abuses' probably its best feature - asynchronous nature of JavaScript. That is not new, many languages have async libraries, but as Ryan Dahl said in one of his earliest speeches on node, JS is *perfect* for it. And mainly because of the closures and other concepts built into it.

So final answer would be the author of the book you're quoting has poorly expressed his thoughts or is simply wrong. It was a toy language and didn't mean to be used for such variety of use cases as it is today. But it evolved, just as Java or PHP did (don't forget PHP didn't have OOP support that seems so obvious now until v5). Other languages are just picking up goodies that JavaScript proved to be more efficient for certain use cases. Overall, my thoughts are that JavaScript hasn't been used properly from the start, and that's the case it had been called 'deficient'. Now developers got chance to explore its magnificence.

Comment: I wouldn't say other languages have picked up goodies from Javascript (such as closures and anonymous functions).  Just because Javascript also has them doesn't mean Javascript originated them.   How about we revise and revise Javascript, so that at last it becomes Ruby?

Comment: Didn't say JS originated them, far from it. Quote you've pasted sort of compared JavaScript to Java and PHP, so I've just stayed in the context. But gotta say, JS uses closures much more extensively than any other language I've seen. Other languages use them here and there, when the usage is appropriate. With JS you use them almost everywhere.